# String manipulation using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, stored-procedures

I have a colon separated string such as

```
@var='apple;banana;snake;mango;dog';
@tobedeleted='banana';
```

and suppose if I need to delete banana from @var using stored procs and the resulting string should look like

```
@var='apple;snake;mago;dog'
```

How is this achievable using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I would go for a proc, but it depends entirely on the context of what you're attempting to achieve.

If you INSIST on a proc;

```
CREATE PROC dbo.NoMoreBananas
    @FullString     VARCHAR(1000),
    @StringToDelete VARCHAR(50),
    @OutString      VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET @OutString = REPLACE(REPLACE(@FullString, @StringToDelete, ''), ';;', ';')
    IF(LEFT(@OutString, 1) = ';')
    BEGIN
        SET @OutString = RIGHT(@OutString, LEN(@OutString)-1)
    END
    IF(RIGHT(@OutString, 1) = ';')
    BEGIN
        SET @OutString = LEFT(@OutString, LEN(@OutString)-1)
    END
END
GO


DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @FullString varchar(1000)       = 'apple;banana;snake;mango;dog'
DECLARE @StringToDelete varchar(50)     = 'banana'
DECLARE @OutString varchar(1000)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[NoMoreBananas] 
   @FullString
  ,@StringToDelete
  ,@OutString OUTPUT

SELECT @OutString
GO
```

Comment: Realised that I didn't use OUTPUT properly

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all tokens are delimited on both the left and right, replace then remove the added delimiters

```
select substring(replace(';' + @var + ';', ';' + @remove + ';', ';'), 2, len(@var) - len(@remove) - 1)
```

Comment: This solution will raise an error if both strings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(';;'+@var+';;',';'+@tobedeleted,''),';;','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @var = REPLACE (@var + ';', @tobedeleted + ';', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 REPLACE function, one to remove the word, two to remove duplicated ";", if it apears:

```
set @var = REPLACE( REPLACE(@var, @tobedeleted, ''), ';;', ';')
```

Comment: What if 'dog' has to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize database. Would be much simpler if those values (`'apple;banana;snake;mango;dog'`) could be stored within table. In this case, a simple `DELETE` statement will solve the problem:

```
DELETE dbo.Fruits
WHERE Name = N'banana'
```